# jQuery resizing window after filter is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a page that has `ul#tiles` and `li.tile`.
The default filtering for the page view is filter by all(presents every tile).
When I filter the list I still have the extra space and scroller for the rest of the page - extra blank page.

I want to remove the extra space if the current filter presents less views than the filter  before it.

The `resize` event does fire and `resizeFunction()` is being called but the screen isn't changing.

```
function resizeFunction() {
    var tilesHeight = $('#tiles').height();
    window.resizeTo(window.screen.availWidth, tilesHeight + 50);
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeFunction();
});
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle or put your html/css within the question?

Comment: Just a side question, out of curiosity, how many `li#tile` do you have?

Comment: It depends, it can be 400 or 4 depending on the request from the server, the filtering is on the client side.

Comment: Having 400 elements with the same ID means 399 in excess. ID must be unique (that's the point of a unique identifier).

Comment: The id is for the ul not for the li's

Comment: in your question >> "`li#tile`"

Comment: Are you talking about a child window?

Answer (score 0):

Window targets the brwoser. To get rid of blank space you will have to target the DOM element that contains your tiles. 
Also make sure no height constrains are present on any parent element. This might even make any resizing function obsolete.

Comment: My DOM element is the ul#tiles - it's height does changes during the filter but the window stays the same